# undefined jwt token react/express

Tags: express, react-redux, jwt

I am implementing a JWT authentication on a login/registration system. When there is a successful login/registration I am setting a user token in localStorage.

Problem is when I check my localStorage the user key is present but the value is undefined. I think the issue might be in my axios post or in my express file but I can't quite figure it out.

```
// my action creator
export function login(user, history) {
return async (dispatch) => {
  axios.post('/api/login', { user })
  .then(res => {
      dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATED });
      localStorage.setItem('user', res.data.token);
      history.push('/');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      dispatch({
          type: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR,
          payload: 'Invalid email or password'
      });
  });
 };
}
```

The data is reaching my api correctly. The item is being set but the value res.data.token is undefined.. Below is my express file

```
// login.js (/api/login)
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
var email = req.body.user.email;
var password = req.body.user.password;
// TODO: create db file and import connection
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "dbname",
    port: 3307
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        connection.query("SELECT ID, Password FROM Users WHERE Email = ?", [email], function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Could not find account');
                res.send(err);
            } else {

                var id = result[0].ID;

                bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].Password, function(err, result) {
                    if(result) {
                        console.log(id);
                        res.json({ id });
                    } else {
                        console.log('Incorrect password');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Since the res.data.token in my action creator is returning undefined does that mean the response in my express file ( res.json([id]) ) is just returning defined?

Comment: Can you share what actual response you are getting from express ?

Comment: the axios response is a null object..the id is correct in my express variable though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending the response properly.

`res.json([id]);` Its just sending the `array of id`. That's why `res.data.token` is undefined. as `data` does not contain an object.

Send proper object like:

`res.json({id});`

Comment: that's a good point i am not sure why I was sending it in an array when I wrote it..EDIT* Now when I console.log(res.data) in my action creator i get my id from express..but res.data.token is still undefined..shouldn't jwt take what's in res.data and create the token?

Comment: I will edit in original question..i also edited my comment above. As the id is now sending I think it has something to do with .token or jwt in my action creator and not the express file but I could be wrong

Comment: If id is being sent to react it than your code is good. you are not sending token in response at all.

Comment: so if i adjust the response to { token: id } it will work and the value in localStorage is correct but not encrypyted so my code has no web token? maybe I need to read a little more on how it works because I thought the .token would create an encrypted string of the id for localStorage throught JWT but it seems i just dont fully understand it

Comment: @Ryne Have a look at: https://medium.com/@patrykcieszkowski/jwt-authentication-in-express-js-ee898b87a60
It might help